# React Native / Featherjs : How to make the API detects from which app i'm connecting?

Tags: reactjs, api, native

I've 2 apps made on react native / featherjs. These apps connect to the same API.

But i would like to send a parameter to the API, like "source: "test", to know from which app comes the call.

Is there a way to do that ? I can't modify the API myself, i'm just in charge of the front of the apps.

To be clearer, i've this code in the 2 stores of my 2 apps :

(this is a call to get a town list)

```
constructor() {
        const restClient = rest(API_URL);
        const api = feathers();
        this.app = feathers()
            .configure(restClient.axios(axios))
            .configure(hooks())
            .configure(authentication({
                storage: AsyncStorage
            }));
    }
    @action
    async onGetVilles(text) {
        let query;
        if (isNaN(text)) {
            let valueNs = text.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
            let valueS = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
            let valueF = valueNs.replace(/-/, " ");
            let valueG = text.replace(/ /, "'");
            let valueH = valueG.replace(/ /, "-");
            query = {
                query: {
                    $or: [
                        {ville: {$like: `${valueNs}%`}},
                        {ville: {$like: `${valueS}%`}},
                        {ville: {$like: `${valueF}%`}},
                        {ville: {$like: `${valueG}%`}},
                        {ville: {$like: `${valueH}%`}},
                    ],
                    "$limit": 20,
                }
            }
        } else {
            query = {
                query: {
                    CP: {$like: text + '%'},
                    "$limit": 20,
                }
            }
        }
        const rep = await this.app.service("villes").find(query)
            .then((response) => {
                return response;
            })
        return rep;
    }
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: I was thinking that i could use headers to pass informations ? i can see that on featherjs doc
```app.service('messages').create({
  text: 'A message from a REST client'
}, {
  headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'FeathersJS' }
});
```
So i could create a property saying i come from a particular app ?

Comment: Ok in the end, my boss told me to rebuild an API with nest and forget feathersjs